# Angular 2 formControlName inside a child component of formGroup

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-components, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to build a wizard type form using Reactive Forms. Following is a snippet of my code

```
<form [formGroup]="pizzaForm" novalidate>
    <wp-wizard navBarLocation="top">
         <wp-wizard-step title="Dough">
              <input type="text" id="dough" [formControlName]="dough">
```

wizard and wizard-step are working without forms.

When I implement them with Reactive Forms and run the application, I'm seeing errors like below.

```
Cannot find control with name: '[object Object]'
```

I'm assuming this is because `dough` `formControlName` is not immediate child of `pizzaForm` `formGroup`. Not sure though. If that is the cause, how do I fix this problem? I have few fields in each wizard steps and I think all the fields should still belong to the same form so I can track the form validity. Or may be I should have different forms for each wizard step ?

Please let me know if more information is required to understand the issue.

Comment: Do you have a `dogh` varaible in the component?

Comment: Yes, I do. ~10char

Comment: And you want to pass in a string called "dough" to the [formControlName] property?

Comment: I have `FormControl` variable named `dough`. `dough` is bound to `pizzaForm` using `FormBinding`

Comment: `formControlName` should be bound to a string if I'm not mistaken. Could you please upload a plnkr example?

Comment: you are right. I should be using `formControlName="dough"` instead of `[formControlName]="dough"`. Also I did not need to create FormControl dough explicitly. Just creating it with FormBuilder will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I mistakenly used `[formControlName]` instead of `formControlName`